# Difference between service user permission set licenses & feature licence

Tags: permissions, licenses, permission-sets

I wanted to understand the difference between permission sets and permission set licences. The text in the documentation is very generic and I was looking for examples. (I finally got it ) 
I my oldest dev org created in 2013 I have only the Orders Platform perm set licence. In the org created in July 2016 I have a few more. However I can't find  any of the ones mentioned here [permission set licenses](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer16/release-notes/rn_editions_tracking_user_license_usage.htm). This left me baffled because

1. I can't see the CRM, sales and service user permission set licences - I have access to these bunch:

   - Sales Console User
   - Orders Platform
   - Identity Connect
   - Analytics Cloud  xxx

Are they not available in dev orgs? Why the new permission licences types didn't get  allocated in my old org just like in the newer one.

2. I don't understand the difference (the need for) Service user permission set licence and the Service Cloud User feature licence.

has anybody got thoughts on this he would like to share?

Answer (score -2):

Seems clear from the posted documentation link that development orgs aren't included.

[image]